# Disconect+Connect (Reload) INTERFACE USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, devcon

I'm having an issue with a KVM and windows 10 that is well know [1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-kvm-issue-keyboard-not-initializing/03d82b93-5c76-4077-a5f3-365b9d4a4aa8), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsinsiders/comments/u7xcht/keyboardmouse_stops_working_on_usbkvm_switch/) and [3](https://superuser.com/questions/1009620/kvm-switch-not-recognizing-usb-devices-on-windows-10). When I switch my KVM to this Win10 machine, the USB interface doesnt recognize the devices plugged to the KVM so I have to manually unplug and plug the USB cable to make it work as intended.

I want to automate this process. (suggestions are welcome).

I thought about running an [.ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com) script that would call something like [pnputils](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples). I think that the right syntax here is `interface` and not `device`, as there will be no devices connected for the reason stated above. pnp has calls for `enable-device` and `disable-device`, but not for the interfaces ):

I have ran `pnputils /enum-interfaces /enabled` with and without the said USB cable being connected and the diff between the logs is:

```
Instance ID:                    
Device Description:         Generic USB Hub 
Class Name:                 USB 
Class GUID:                 {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}  
Manufacturer Name:          (Standard USB HUBs) 
Status:                     Started 
Driver Name:                usbhub3.inf

Instance ID:                USB\VID_046D&PID_C53F\6&55a180b&0&3 
Device Description:         USB Composite Device    
Class Name:                 USB 
Class GUID:                 {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}  
Manufacturer Name:          (Standard USB Host Controller)  
Status:                     Started 
Driver Name:                usb.inf

Instance ID:                USB\VID_046D&PID_C228\7&2aaff80b&0&1    
Device Description:         USB Composite Device    
Class Name:                 USB 
Class GUID:                 {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}  
Manufacturer Name:          (Standard USB Host Controller)  
Status:                     Started 
Driver Name:                usb.inf 

Instance ID:                USB\VID_05E3&PID_0608\5&326c0cbc&0&1    
Device Description:         Generic USB Hub 
Class Name:                 USB 
Class GUID:                 {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}  
Manufacturer Name:          (Standard USB HUBs) 
Status:                     Started 
Driver Name:                usbhub3.inf

Instance ID:                USB\VID_1235&PID_8202\6&55a180b&0&2 
Device Description:         USB Composite Device    
Class Name:                 USB 
Class GUID:                 {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}  
Manufacturer Name:          (Standard USB Host Controller)  
Status:                     Started 
Driver Name:                usb.inf

Instance ID:                USB\VID_046D&PID_C229\7&2aaff80b&0&2    
Device Description:         USB Composite Device    
Class Name:                 USB 
Class GUID:                 {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}  
Manufacturer Name:          (Standard USB Host Controller)  
Status:                     Started 
Driver Name:                usb.inf
```

Is there a way to do what I want? Maybe reloading the USB driver (`usbhub3.inf`)?